# Selective Synchronization of Connection Tracking State Tables between Firewalls using conntrackd

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, iptables

I have got three firewalls running on Ubuntu 12.04 Server in the ACTIVE/BACKUP/BACKUP mode. The firewalls are using iptables. I am using Keepalived and Conntrack-Tools for the "High Availability" and connection tracking state table synchronization.

What i want to achieve here is to make the synchronization of the state tables to be selective. For instance, if i have 3 connections (A, B, C) in the state table entry in the master, then i would want the BACKUP 1 firewall to sync only connections A and B, and the BACKUP 2 firewall to sync only connections A and C.

Is there a way to apply such a filter and to make the synchronization selective?

Comment: I read somewhere that conntrackd has got the feature for selective replication.
But there's so less documentation that i cannot find anything.